How to monitor database for uptime?
Is there a free method to check if your wordpress database is online? basically if the site shows the message: error establishing a database connection then I want it to email me

I think this could use some additional context in order to narrow it down to a more specific question... It's not clear what sort of access to the database which you have, or specifically what sort of "method" you are looking for (there are many many ways to accomplish this both within WordPress and without, leaving this question ambigious and open to opinion). And just to be absolutely sure: the only situation in which you would like to be emailed is if the site cannot connect to the database, and not for any other situation in which the site might become unavailable or go offline?

Yes, you can set up a free method to check if your WordPress database is online and get an email if the site shows the "Error Establishing a Database Connection" message. You can achieve this by adding a simple PHP script to your WordPress theme or via a custom plugin.
Step-by-Step Solution:
Create a Custom Plugin or Add Code to functions.php: You can either create a custom plugin or add the following code to your theme's functions.php file. The code will check the database connection periodically and send an email if it fails.
Add the Database Check Code:
Add this code to your functions.php or create a new plugin with it:
 <?php

function check_db_connection() {
    global $wpdb;

    // Attempt to connect to the database
    if (is_wp_error($wpdb->db_connect())) {
        // Send email notification if there's a problem with the database connection
        $to = 'youremail@example.com';
        $subject = 'WordPress Database Connection Error';
        $message = 'Your WordPress site is currently having issues establishing a database connection.';
        $headers = 'From: Your Site <noreply@yoursite.com>' . "\r\n";

        wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}

// Hook this function to run periodically using WordPress cron jobs
add_action('check_db_connection_hook', 'check_db_connection');

// Schedule the event if it's not already scheduled
if (!wp_next_scheduled('check_db_connection_hook')) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'check_db_connection_hook');
}

Explanation:
This code uses WordPress's $wpdb object to check the database connection.
If the connection fails (checked using is_wp_error()), it sends an email notification to your specified email address.
The check is scheduled to run hourly using WordPress's cron system.
Set Up Email:
Make sure to replace 'youremail@example.com' with your actual email address.
To ensure that emails are sent correctly, you can install an SMTP plugin like WP Mail SMTP if your hosting has issues with PHP's mail() function.
Activate WordPress Cron Jobs: WordPress's cron system works when a visitor accesses your site, so if your site has low traffic, it may not run often enough. To make sure the cron jobs run regularly, you can set up a real cron job on your server (optional).
On Linux servers, add this to your crontab to trigger WordPress cron every hour:
bash
wget -q -O - http://yourdomain.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron > /dev/null 2>&1

Adjust the Check Frequency (Optional): If you want the checks to occur more or less frequently, you can change the schedule in wp_schedule_event(). Possible values are hourly, twicedaily, or daily.
Now, your WordPress site will automatically check the database connection and send you an email if it detects an issue.

It appears dead_db() is the function that shows that error message. It's (kind of) a drop-in, so if you add a file at wp-content/db-error.php, you can have WordPress run any functions you want when it encounters a database error, including sending an email to someone.

I would probably just use a generic uptime monitoring service like UptimeRobot or StatusCake. They both offer free plans.
When the database connection is unsuccessful, you would get a 500 status code. This basic check works with both services.
Wit UptimeRobot you could even check for a specific text that needs to be available on the site to verify, that you not only get a 200 status code, but the site acutally works.

This code, when saved as the file db-error.php in wp-content, does three things when the database isn't accessible: 1) shows a 503 Error page, 2) emails the addrress entered in the variables section, and 3) logs the error to the file mysql-crashes.txt. But keep in mind this requires user traffic to hit the site to send the email and log the error; there is no cron function. And this also requires PHP mail to be working on the server.
<?php header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable'); ?>

<?php 
$to = "me@example.com"; 
$subject = "Database down"; 
$message = "Database down"; 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n"; 
$headers .= "X-Mailer: php\n"; 
$headers .= "From: \"Admin\" <me@example.com\n"; 
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 
?> 

<?php
$file = '/home/wp-content/mysql-crashes.txt';

$time = date('F j, Y, g:i:s a') . "\n"; 

file_put_contents($file, $time, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            h1, p {
                font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 26px;
                color: #333;
                }
            p {
                font-size: 16px;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>We're currently experiencing some temporary technical issues<br />Please check back soon</p></center>
    </body>
</html>

